# how can I add a link in the top nav bar in onet.xml for a custom page?

Tags: navigation, site-template, top-link-bar

I a custom site definition, I have two modules :

- the classic default module to provision the default.aspx
- a custom mypage to provision a custom mypage.aspx

I want to add in the top navigation bar a link to this page. So I set up my module like this, according the documentation:

```
    <Module Name="MyPage"
            Url="">
        <File
            Url="mypage.aspx"
            Type="Ghostable">
            <View List="Lists/mylist"
                  BaseViewID="0"
                  WebPartZoneID="Left"
                 />

            <NavBarPage Name="My custom page"
                        ID="1002"
                        Position="End" />
            <NavBarPage Name="My custom page"
                        ID="0"
                        Position="Start" />
        </File>
    </Module>
```

the pages are provisioned successfully, but the top nav bar is broken and empty.
Is it the correct way to add a link in the top bar ?

Comment: If you solved the Q youself, please add as answer and mark as answer when you can

Comment: @Anders Rask: the actual issue is solved, but I'm still wondering what is the source of the issue... how can I deal with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can redefined the navbars like this :

```
<NavBars>
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;"
            Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;"
            Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;"
            ID="1002" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Documents;"
            Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;"
            Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"
            Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;"
            ID="1004" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Lists;"
            Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;"
            Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"
            Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;"
            ID="1003" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Discussions;"
            Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;"
            Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"
            Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;"
            ID="1006" />
</NavBars>
```

But I don't understand why it's a prerequisite for my link to work